# Could not load file or assembly - asp.net mvc app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

trying to work on a mvc 3 app, using visual studio 2010. The app compiles fine. However, failing at runtime.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'InnVue.BOA.RoomControl' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'InnVue.BOA.RoomControl' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'InnVue.BOA.RoomControl' could not be loaded.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = InnVue.BOA.RoomControl
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: InnVue.BOA.RoomControl | Domain ID: 10
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/KHAN/Documents/GitHub/innvue/InnVue.InnDesk/InnVue.InnDesk/InnVue.InnDesk/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\KHAN\Documents\GitHub\innvue\InnVue.InnDesk\InnVue.InnDesk\InnVue.InnDesk\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\KHAN\Documents\GitHub\innvue\InnVue.InnDesk\InnVue.InnDesk\InnVue.InnDesk\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/KHAN/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/41f4bb6c/382c05ac/InnVue.BOA.RoomControl.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/KHAN/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/41f4bb6c/382c05ac/InnVue.BOA.RoomControl/InnVue.BOA.RoomControl.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/KHAN/Documents/GitHub/innvue/InnVue.InnDesk/InnVue.InnDesk/InnVue.InnDesk/bin/InnVue.BOA.RoomControl.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

And the stack trace is :

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'InnVue.BOA.RoomControl' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'InnVue.BOA.RoomControl' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'InnVue.BOA.RoomControl' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9942412
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +456
```

I have confirmed :

InnVue.BOA.RoomControl.dll is indeed 64bit dll

Assemblies referenced by InnVue.BOA.RoomControl.dll are also referenced by the main project.

Is there any way to track down exactly where this is breaking ? the information provided in stack trace is not very obvious .

Answer (score 0):

The simple test to test out your assembly references if it have been added properly to your project with **copy local is true.** Try to deploy a **release** build to your **local IIS** and try to run your project. probably your application will not run due to missing assemblies, keep fixing it before going back and package your web app to test it out on Azure.

Also, I use **Assembly binding log viewer**, this would tell you exactly what is the missing assembly that do not exist in GAC or your bin directory.

Download link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: interestingly, the project runs fine in local IIS, but debugging still does not work. Does that give any clue?

Comment: delete your IIS deployment, including the bin directory, push a new DEBUG build, attach the w3wp process and run the app. You will be able to debug the app. you have to make sure that you attach the right process, this is the key. otherwise you won't be able to debug against IIS.